# knockout.js click in one viewmodel and based on that render other viewmodel

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

```
    <div data-bind="with: SimpleListModel">  
<div data-bind="foreach: parents">   
        <span data-bind="text: parentname"></span> 
    </div>
</div>

<div data-bind="with: SimpleListModel2">  
    <div data-bind="foreach: childrens">   
        <span data-bind="text: childname"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my viewmodel

```
var parentsdata= [
{ parentid:1, parentname: "Danny" },{parentid:2, parentname: "Peter" },{parentid:3, parentname: "shawn" }];

var childdata= [
{ parentid:1, childrens: [
    { childname: "child1"},
    { childname: "child2"}]
},
{ parentid:2, childrens: [
    { childname: "child1"},
    { childname: "child2"}]
}];

var SimpleListModel = function(parents) {
  var self= this;
 self.parents= ko.observableArray(parents);
};

var SimpleListModel2 = function(childrens) {
 var self= this;
 self.childrens= ko.observableArray(childrens);
};

var masterVM = (function () {
         var self = this;         
         self.SimpleListModel= new SimpleListModel(parentsdata);
          self.SimpleListModel1= new SimpleListModel1(parentsdata);

})();

ko.applyBindings(masterVM);
```

I want to make parentname clickable so that when i click my parentname it's childs are populated in no 2 viewmodel. how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i like the answer posted by `@M. Ihsan` above but there are few corrections.

instead of using a function to filter `children` **every time you click on a parent**, you can use [`ko.computed`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) to do the job automatically. that way you can also able to change the parent dynamically and your two Parent and Child models stays untouched.

```js
var parentsdata = [{ parentid: 1, parentname: "Danny" }, { parentid: 2, parentname: "Peter" }, { parentid: 3, parentname: "shawn" }];

var childdata = [{ parentid: 1, childrens: [{ childname: "DannyChild1" }, { childname: "DannyChild2" } ] }, { parentid: 2, childrens: [{ childname: "PeterChild1" }, { childname: "PeterChild2" } ] } ];

var SimpleListModel = function(parents) {
  var self = this;
  self.parents = ko.observableArray(parents);
};

var SimpleListModel2 = function(childrens) {
  var self = this;
  self.childrens = ko.observableArray(childrens);
};

var masterVM = (function() {
  var self = this;
  self.SimpleListModel = new SimpleListModel(parentsdata);
  self.SimpleListModel2 = new SimpleListModel2(childdata);
  self.selectedParent = ko.observable(); // holds selected parent
  self.ParentChildrens = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.SimpleListModel2.childrens(), function(child) {
      return child.parentid == self.selectedParent();
    })[0];
  });
  self.parentClick = function(data) {
    self.selectedParent(data.parentid);
  }
})();
ko.applyBindings(masterVM);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="with: SimpleListModel">
  <div data-bind="foreach: parents">
    <span data-bind="text: parentname, click: parentClick"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-bind="with: ParentChildrens">
  <div data-bind="foreach: childrens">
    <span data-bind="text: childname"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't have `SampleListViewModel1` there. You need to change it to `SampleListViewModel2` then pass `childdata` during initialization to that object instead of `parentdata`.

Then you can create a function in SampleListViewModel1 which will pass the selected parent to parent object (masterVM). Then in masterVM, try to get children from the selected parent and store it in an observable object. In the view you just need to show this observable object.

```js
var parentsdata = [
  { parentid:1, parentname: "Danny" },
  {parentid:2, parentname: "Peter" },
  {parentid:3, parentname: "shawn" }
];

var childdata = [
  { parentid:1, childrens: [
    { childname: "child1 of parent1"},
    { childname: "child2 of parent1"}]
  },
  { parentid:2, childrens: [
    { childname: "child1 of parent2"},
    { childname: "child2 of parent2"}]
  }
];

var SimpleListModel = function(parents, parentObject) {
  var self = this;

  // this is used to get the reference to parent object (masterVM)
  self.parentObject = parentObject;

  self.parents = ko.observableArray(parents);

  // call this function on click and trigger the parent function which will do the filtration
  self.selectParent = function(parent) {
    self.parentObject.selectParent(parent);
   }
};

var SimpleListModel2 = function(childrens) {
  var self = this;
  self.childrens = ko.observableArray(childrens);
};

function masterVM() {
  var self = this;         
 
  // pass its own object during initialization
  self.SimpleListModel = new SimpleListModel(parentsdata, self);

  self.SimpleListModel2 = new SimpleListModel2(childdata);

  // store children of the selected parent
  self.childForSelectedParent = ko.observable(null);

  // get the children of the selected parent
  self.selectParent = function(parent) {
    var children = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.SimpleListModel2.childrens(), function(children) {
        return children.parentid === parent.parentid;
    });
    if(children)
      self.childForSelectedParent(new SimpleListModel2(children.childrens));
    else
      self.childForSelectedParent(null);
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new masterVM());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>Click on any of the name</div>

<div data-bind="with: SimpleListModel">  
  <div data-bind="foreach: parents">   
    <span data-bind="text: parentname, click: $parent.selectParent"></span> 
  </div>
</div>

<div data-bind="with: childForSelectedParent">  
  <div data-bind="foreach: childrens">   
    <span data-bind="text: childname"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```